# How to manage situational-optional input parameters using pydantic BaseModel?

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I have an input class defined by `pydantic.BaseModel`, some of the parameters are situational-optional. See the following example.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Product(BaseModel):
    name: str
    sale_price: float | None = None
    cost_manufacture: float | None = None
    cost_transport: float | None = None
    earning_ratio: float | None = None
```

The required relationship is:

- If `sale_price` is provided, then `cost_manufacture`, `cost_transport`, and `earning_ratio` are not needed. They can just be the default `None`.
- If `sale_price` is not provided, the `cost_manufacture`, `cost_transport`, and `earning_ratio` are needed.

My code above cannot include this relationship, since all the parameters are simply optional.

I thought about adding plain-text description like below. However, it is not ideal, since it takes too much time for the user to read.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Product(BaseModel):
    name: str
    sale_price: float | None = Field(
        default=None,
        description="If you have this value, you don't have to provide cost_manufacture, cost_transport, or earning_ratio.",
    )
    cost_manufacture: float | None = Field(
        default=None,
        description="If you don't have sale_price, you have to provide cost_manufacture, cost_transport, and earning_ratio.",
    )
    cost_transport: float | None = Field(
        default=None,
        description="If you don't have sale_price, you have to provide cost_manufacture, cost_transport, and earning_ratio.",
    )
    earning_ratio: float | None = Field(
        default=None,
        description="If you don't have sale_price, you have to provide cost_manufacture, cost_transport, and earning_ratio.",
    )
```

Could you please show me how to realize it elegantly? Here I have to use `pydantic.BaseModel` since it is for the input of my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the requirements using a [root validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#root-validators):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class Product(BaseModel):
    name: str
    sale_price: float | None = None
    cost_manufacture: float | None = None
    cost_transport: float | None = None
    earning_ratio: float | None = None

    @root_validator
    def validate(cls, values):
        if values['sale_price'] is None:
            for attr in ['cost_manufacture', 'cost_transport', 'earning_ratio']:
                if values[attr] is None:
                    raise ValueError(f'{attr} is required when sale_price is not set')
        return values
```

---

Here's a test suite to verify the behavior:

```py
import itertools
import pytest
from rootvaltest import Product


def test_product_with_only_sale_price_works():
    Product(name="example", sale_price=1.0)


def test_product_with_all_costs_works():
    Product(name="example", cost_manufacture=1.0, cost_transport=1.0, earning_ratio=1.0)


def test_product_with_only_name_fails():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        Product(name="example")


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "attr1,attr2",
    itertools.combinations(["cost_manufacture", "cost_transport", "earning_ratio"], 2),
)
def test_incomplete_product_fails(attr1, attr2):
    kwargs = {
        attr1: 1.0,
        attr2: 1.0,
    }

    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        Product(name="example", **kwargs)
```

Test output:

```
========================================== test session starts ==========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.3, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
plugins: anyio-3.7.0
collected 6 items

test_rootvaltest.py::test_product_with_only_sale_price_works PASSED                               [ 16%]
test_rootvaltest.py::test_product_with_all_costs_works PASSED                                     [ 33%]
test_rootvaltest.py::test_product_with_only_name_fails PASSED                                     [ 50%]
test_rootvaltest.py::test_incomplete_product_fails[cost_manufacture-cost_transport] PASSED        [ 66%]
test_rootvaltest.py::test_incomplete_product_fails[cost_manufacture-earning_ratio] PASSED         [ 83%]
test_rootvaltest.py::test_incomplete_product_fails[cost_transport-earning_ratio] PASSED           [100%]
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. It is obviously better than just the plain-text solution in my code in my question.